# How to use Win32 API to talk to a com port (RS232)

Tags: windows, winapi, serial-port

I am trying to use win32 API to talk to a com port
I found this 
http://www.robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf

```
hSerial = CreateFile("COM1",
GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
0,
0,
OPEN_EXISTING,
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
0);
```

I use VS2008 and it complains 
error C2664: 'CreateFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'

OK, I guess it doesn't like "COM1" to be char* type,

I tried casting it LPCWSTR("COM1"), then it compiles with no problem.

However, it returns "ERROR opening serial port -1", so it doesn't find the com port successfully. I guess direct casting is not the right way?

Please tell me what I should do to make this work.

the msdn is not that helpful
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx

I don't know what the "gszPort" means there

Answer (score 3):

Try `_T("COM1")` instead of `LPCWSTR("COM1")`. It's called [Generic-Text Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7dzey6h6.aspx). I don't actually know whether that is the problem, but using `_T` is the right way to it.

Also, when Windows API calls return an error condition (like *-1*) you can use the [Last-Error Code (using `GetLastError` and `FormatMessage`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680347.aspx) to get a more detailed description of the error.

Comment: Hi Michael, _T("COM1") gives error identifier not found, should I include some header files? TEXT("") works for me

Comment: +1 Michael.

Alfred, you're missing an underscore in that symbol. _T("COM1")

Under UNICODE builds, _T("") maps to L"", which is what TEXT("") maps to, which is why that works for you; and under MBCS/ANSI builds, _T("") maps to "" which is why your original doesn't work for you because windows functions are mapped to A/W versions that accept either Ansi or Unicode strings depending on whether the build target is UNICODE or not.

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried both _T and __T, no luck, I guess it is the unicode problem, will try later. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

For a Unicode build, `CreateFile` maps to `CreateFileW` which expects "wide" character strings.  You can solve the immediate problem by prefixing your string constant with L, like this:

```
CreateFile(L"COM1", ...);
```

Some people would suggest explicitly using the wide version:

```
CreateFileW(L"COM1", ...);
```

Or you can explicitly use the "ANSI" version, even in a Unicode build:

```
CreateFileA("COM1", ...);
```

If you want to be able to build Unicode and ANSI builds, you can use a macro that optionally includes the L prefix.  There are two versions of this macro:  `TEXT(x)` and `_T(x)`.  If I recall correctly, the former comes from the Windows API via `<tchar.h>` and the latter comes from Microsoft's implementation of the C runtime library.  Since this is a Windows API, I'd use the `TEXT` version.

```
CreateFile(TEXT("COM"), ...);
```

Nowadays, it's probably not worth keeping the backward compatibility for ANSI.  All versions of Windows released in the past decade use Unicode internally, so if you try to use the ANSI versions, the strings are going to be widened at run time.  So I wouldn't worry about the macros and just prefix string literals with `L` except in very special circumstances.